# How to shadow an interface property?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I've got a generic Interface that inherits from a non-generic Interface.  Somehow the compiler does't like how I've done this.  I'd appreciate any help in figuring out how to accomplish this inheritance in a manner that the compiler doesn't whine about.

```
Public Interface IMessage

    Property MessageType As UInt16

    Property Payload As Object

End Interface


Public Interface IMessage(Of T)
    Inherits IMessage

    Shadows Property Payload As T

End Interface


Public Class Message(Of T)
    Implements IMessage(Of T)    '  <-- This line is highlighted in VS.



    Public Property MessageType As UInt16 = 0 Implements IMessage(Of T).MessageType

    Public Property Payload As T = Nothing Implements IMessage(Of T).Payload

End Class
```

> Class 'Message' must implement 'Property Payload As Object' for
>   interface 'IMessage'.  Implementing property must have matching
>   'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.

Answer (score 4):

```
  Shadows Property Payload As T
```

By using *Shadows*, you tell the compiler that this Payload property *intentionally* does not match the base property.  So the generic interface has *two* properties, one `As Object`, the other `As T`.  Implementing the interface therefore requires you to implement them both:

```
Public Class Message(Of T)
    Implements IMessage(Of T)

    Public Property MessageType As UInt16 = 0 Implements IMessage(Of T).MessageType
    Public Property Payload As T = Nothing Implements IMessage(Of T).Payload
    Private Property Payload1 As Object Implements IMessage.Payload
        Get
            Return Payload
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Payload = CType(value, T)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This is not what you want to do, I'm sure.  So it is probably best to address the real problem, there is no visible use for the non-generic interface.  If you have one anyway then the snippet shows you what to do about it.

Comment: mmm.  you are correct in that this is not the solution I was hoping for.  The value of the generic is that I could get some type checking on some objects.  The value of the non-generic was so that I could define function parameters that took an IMessage, yet pass in an IMessage(Of Book) and an IMessage(Of Author).  Well.. back to the design board.  Thanks for the answer.